# I got a super weird crash on Fabric onResume of my FragmentActivity, at the super.onResume()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle, onresume

What does this mean, and can be fixed somehow?
Not crashing in my code, but in the super of the FragmentActivity, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1688)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:5505)
   at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5983)
   at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1253)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:485)
   at nl.hgrams.passenger.activities.PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.onResume(PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.java:576)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1270)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6788)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2844)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2858)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1575)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

This is my onResume():

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(addedPitstopBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("addedPitstop"));

    if (PSApplicationClass.getInstance().pref.getUserId(PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.this) != null) {
        renewSettings();

        PSApplicationClass.getInstance().pref.setIsBackground(this, false);
        if (PSApplicationClass.getInstance().pref.isRefetchUser(PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.this)) {
            PSApplicationClass.getInstance().pref.setRefetchUser(PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.this, false);
            MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.changeFirebaseToken(PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.this);
        }
    }
}
```

But it directly crashed at onResume, so it didn't pass to the next line. Also tried to reproduce me, but could not.
The user had a: LG G-Pad 8.3
[image: 1]]

Comment: The operating system of the user is 7 so it has multi window support. in multi window when the user changes windows size `onResume` will be called multiple times repeatedly. maybe it causes exception. you should also test this condition.

Comment: so I need to try on a TAB, with multiple windows support, to try to get it to crash then, in order to reproduce?

Comment: i think phones with android 7 or newer also has multi window. to go to multi window long press on recent tasks

Comment: Also, I checked and the LG G-Pad 8.3 has 4.4 upgradable to 5.0 via OTA. My question is how is it possible to have Android 7.1.2 and not be rooted? (the fabric picture says NO) am I looking at the wrong device?

Comment: i am not sure but some one can flash a phone to clear it and then install any custom ROM to it

Comment: but for that, it needs to be Rooted, no? Anyhow, thanks! Looking into this, did not found the crash, but did found some issues that I need to fix. Did not test this edge case